# Line integral along straight horizontal line

Tags: integration

I have an issue with the following line integral: $\int_0^5 f(s)\, ds$. 
This integral goes along the straight horizontal line (from $0$ to $5$). Parametric form of this line is $x=5t$. Then $\text{d}s=(\sqrt{(dx/dt)^2}) \, \text{d}t$ so that $\text{d}s=5 \, \text{d}t$. So my integral becomes:
$\int_0^5 5f(t)\, dt$. Am I right here or are there any other way of computing the line integral along the straight horizontal line?

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Do you mean $\int ^{5}_{0}\mathbf{F}( s)\mathbf{\cdotp }\mathrm{d} s$?

Comment: @K.defaoite, would you please check this question "Line integral for a two cell stringer beam"? This question contains my full solution of the given integral and description that I posted today. And yes, I mean a capitol "F" in the integral.

Comment: It would help to know what the vector field $\mathbf{F}$ is.

Comment: The line integral that I am trying to compute is $\frac {1}{A} * \int_0^5 q/t1 ds $ where "t1" is thickness (not parameter "t") and "q" is some constant that I am trying to compute later. So I assume that F(x,y) is simply 1 here since the problem is in 1D space

Comment: As both $q$ and $t_1$ are constants, shouldn't the integral just be $\frac{5q}{At_1}$? I'm not sure why you're bothering with the whole idea of line integrals if you don't have a non-trivial vector field here.

Comment: So you say that I need just to integrate along the line without making parametric form? Anyway if I do as you say the result I get is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to evaluate this integral one need to parametrize the straight line as follows: $x=t$ when $0<t<5$. Thus, $ds=sqrt((dx/dt)^2) dt$ and our integral becomes $\frac {1}{A} * \int_0^5 \frac{q}{t1} dt$